# What is the polarity of a custom power supply?

Tags: adapter, polarity

I have a custom power adapter ([this one](https://www.metronic.com/it/energia/828-alimentazione-universale-da-rete-600ma-3420744950350.html)), but I do not understand what the correct polarity is, as its tip can be reversed. In the picture I have highlighted the marks in the current situation (so the + sign on the tip corresponds to the + sign on the bottom). What type of polarity is this? Center negative or center positive?

[image]

Comment: 1) Please provide a decipherable photo.

Comment: 2) Check for polarity symbols like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_symbols).

Comment: my camera is really crappy so this is the maximum focus I can obtain. However the only things you can see are the 2 "+" signs as highlighted. I have looked on the power supply for the polarity symbols but there is none.

Answer (score 5):

Your picture is out of focus so we can't see any markings. However, if it is truly custom there is no way of telling just by looking at it. The easiest way if to borrow a meter and measure it.